# Error while installing flask-mysqldb

Tags: flask, python-3.4

I tried to install flask-mysqldb  on my Windows 10 using

flask-mysqldb

but I get this error:

```
running build_ext
    building '_mysql' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat).
```

I'm using Python 3.4.3 Please tell me exactly what I should do to make this work. I went through many solutions but it didn't help me.

Comment: Do you have Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 installed?

Answer (score 0):

PIP install the [mysqlclient](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient) Windows binary before installing flask-mysql.