# How to fix install flask-mysqdb module in windows 10

Tags: python, mysql, flask, windows-10, mysql-python

I am running python 3.7 in windows 10. Trying to work on a flask project with mysql. So whenever I try to install flask-mysqldb module it shows some error.

```
-> pip install flask-mysqldb
Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual 
C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
```

I tried this:
[Python Pip install error with: flask-mysqldb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41206366/python-pip-install-error-with-flask-mysqldb)

[Error Installing flask-mysqldb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51797751/error-installing-flask-mysqldb)

[Error while installing flask-mysqldb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35276503/error-while-installing-flask-mysqldb)

and also download binary file from this
https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient

```
-> pip install .\mysqlclient-1.3.13-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
```

and throw this error

```
mysqlclient-1.3.13-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on 
this platform
```

then I tried to install mysql-connector for c and python. It did installed but nothing changes.

***Is something I missed or something I did wrong ? ***

It will be really helpful if anybody solve this weird problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue. My work around was to use mysql-connector package, which can be installed through pip. Then, create a connection to the MySQL DB through that. Hope this helps!

```
pip install mysql-connector
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew :) That works just fine. Though on Linux flask-mysqldb works why not it works in windows :/ really appreciate your help